# How to use gzip correctly in a makefile?

Tags: makefile, gzip

I'm a `make` newbie, so feel free to correct my syntax for this question.

I want to create a makefile that downloads a bunch of compressed files, uncompresses them and does something with them. Here's my toy example:

```
my_dir/*.txt.gz:
    echo "# obtaining data"
    mkdir -p my_dir
    echo 1 > my_dir/file1.txt
    gzip my_dir/file1.txt
    echo 2 > my_dir/file2.txt
    gzip my_dir/file2.txt

my_dir/*.txt: my_dir/*.txt.gz
    echo "# unzipping data"
    parallel gzip -d ::: my_dir/*.txt.gz

final.txt: my_dir/*.txt
    echo "# doing something with data"
    cat my_dir/*.txt > $@

clean_my_dir:
    rm -rf my_dir
    rm -f final.txt
```

When I run `make final.txt` I get what I expect (`final.txt` contains `1\n2`), but if I run `make final.txt` again (without running `make clean_my_dir`) I get an error:

```
make final.txt
echo "# obtaining data"
# obtaining data
mkdir -p my_dir
echo 1 > my_dir/file1.txt
gzip my_dir/file1.txt
echo 2 > my_dir/file2.txt
gzip my_dir/file2.txt
echo "# unzipping data"
# unzipping data
parallel gzip -d ::: my_dir/*.txt.gz
echo "# unzipping data"
# unzipping data
parallel gzip -d ::: my_dir/*.txt.gz
gzip: can't stat: my_dir/*.txt.gz (my_dir/*.txt.gz.gz): No such file or directory
make: *** [my_dir/file2.txt] Error 1
```

I'm sure I'm making a mistake in the way I set up the targets and the prerequisites: I want `final.txt` to contain the contents of `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`, but these files are initially zipped. How do I tell `make` to call `gzip` when there are compressed files and to not do anything when the uncompressed files are available?

Comment: `*` isn't a wildcard in a make target so `my_dir/*.txt: my_dir/*.txt.gz` is talking about a file with the name `my_dir/*.txt` not the set of files matched by that glob (as you can see in the failing output). Similarly for `my_dir/*.txt.gz:`.

Comment: What should I use then? I tried changing the `*` to `%` but every time I call `make my_dir/%.txt` it recreates the `my_dir/%.txt.gz` target

Comment: `%` is a make wildcard in targets (not a globbing one). It makes a pattern rule; a rule that applies to any listed targets that match that pattern. Post the makefile with `%` wildcards and what you get when you run it. And yes, your `my_dir/%.txt` recipe deletes the input `.txt.gz` files so the next run make will need to generate them again.

Comment: If I remove the gzip command in the `my_dir/%.txt` recipe, the `my_dir/%.txt.gz` recipe gets called every time I run `make my_dir/%.txt`. Shouldn't it just run once? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little experimentation I created to following makefile:

```
COMPRESSED_DIR = my_dir
UNCOMPRESSED_DIR = temp_dir

DEPS = \
    $(UNCOMPRESSED_DIR)/file1.txt \
    $(UNCOMPRESSED_DIR)/file2.txt

##
##  Recipes how to obtain compressed files
##  (may propably not so trivial in your intended application)
##
$(COMPRESSED_DIR)/file1.txt.gz: 
    @echo ""
    @echo "# obtaining $@"
    mkdir -p $(COMPRESSED_DIR)
    echo 1 > $(COMPRESSED_DIR)/file1.txt
    gzip $(COMPRESSED_DIR)/file1.txt

$(COMPRESSED_DIR)/file2.txt.gz: 
    @echo ""
    @echo "# obtaining $@"
    mkdir -p $(COMPRESSED_DIR)
    echo 2 > $(COMPRESSED_DIR)/file2.txt
    gzip $(COMPRESSED_DIR)/file2.txt

## or alternatively:
#$(COMPRESSED_DIR)/%.txt.gz: 
#   @echo ""
#   @echo "# obtaining $@"
#   mkdir -p $(COMPRESSED_DIR)
#   echo $* > $(COMPRESSED_DIR)/$*.txt
#   gzip $(COMPRESSED_DIR)/$*.txt

##
##  Recipe to unpack compressed files
##
$(UNCOMPRESSED_DIR)/%.txt: $(COMPRESSED_DIR)/%.txt.gz
    @echo ""
    @echo "# unpacking $<..."
    mkdir -p $(UNCOMPRESSED_DIR)
    gzip -c -d $< > $@

##
##  Recipe to make final.txt
##
final.txt: $(DEPS)
    @echo ""
    @echo "# doing something with data"
    cat $(UNCOMPRESSED_DIR)/*.txt > final.txt

##
##  Recipe to clean
##
clean:
    rm -rf $(COMPRESSED_DIR)
    rm -rf $(UNCOMPRESSED_DIR)
    rm -f final.txt
```

As pointed out before gzip deletes the txt.gz file and therefore the recipe for creating the txt.gz files is re-executed if making final.txt again.

What I've done is placing the unpacked txt.gz files in a seperate directory and forcing gzip to keep the original file when unpacking. This leads to the following behavior:

If called the first time, the txt.gz files will be created and unpacked and final.txt will be created:

```
# obtaining my_dir/file1.txt.gz
mkdir -p my_dir
echo 1 > my_dir/file1.txt
gzip my_dir/file1.txt

# unpacking my_dir/file1.txt.gz...
mkdir -p temp_dir
gzip -c -d my_dir/file1.txt.gz > temp_dir/file1.txt

# obtaining my_dir/file2.txt.gz
mkdir -p my_dir
echo 2 > my_dir/file2.txt
gzip my_dir/file2.txt

# unpacking my_dir/file2.txt.gz...
mkdir -p temp_dir
gzip -c -d my_dir/file2.txt.gz > temp_dir/file2.txt

# doing something with data
cat temp_dir/*.txt > final.txt
```

If called again (without make clean) the output will be `make:`final.txt' is up to date.`. If a file of $(DEPS) is deleted the corresponding txt.gz file will be re-unpacked. If a .txt.gz file is deleted the .txt.gz file will be re-created and re-unpacked (since it is newer than the existing .txt file).

Alternativly if you've already got all the *.txt.gz files you want to process (and the makefile does not have to create them if they are missing) you can use the following makefile:

```
COMPRESSED_DIR = my_dir
UNCOMPRESSED_DIR = temp_dir

# get a list of all *.txt.gz files within $(COMPRESSED_DIR)
ARCHIVES = $(wildcard $(COMPRESSED_DIR)/*.txt.gz)

# do some magic to modify $(ARCHIVES) into a list of *.txt files to produce
DEPS = $(subst $(COMPRESSED_DIR),$(UNCOMPRESSED_DIR),$(subst .txt.gz,.txt,$(ARCHIVES)))

##
##  Recipe to unpack compressed files
##
$(UNCOMPRESSED_DIR)/%.txt: $(COMPRESSED_DIR)/%.txt.gz
    @echo ""
    @echo "# unpacking $<..."
    mkdir -p $(UNCOMPRESSED_DIR)
    gzip -c -d $< > $@

##
##  Recipe to make final.txt
##
final.txt: $(DEPS)
    @echo "Archives:"
    @echo $(ARCHIVES)
    @echo ""
    @echo "Deps:"
    @echo $(DEPS)
    @echo ""
    @echo "# doing something with data"
    cat $(UNCOMPRESSED_DIR)/*.txt > final.txt

##
##  Recipe to clean
##
clean:
    rm -rf $(UNCOMPRESSED_DIR)
    rm -f final.txt
```

This makefile will uncompress all *.txt.gz files within COMPRESSED_DIR to UNCOMPRESSED_DIR and cat all *.txt files into final.txt.

Comment: Is it possible to not have to specify the recipes for each file individually? I put up a toy example, but in my real makefile I have hundreds of files and I couldn't do them one by one

Comment: The `$(COMPRESSED_DIR)/file1.txt.gz` target can be made a pattern rule by making it `$(COMPRESSED_DIR)/%.txt.gz` and then using `$*` (will be `file1` or `file2` etc.) or `$@` (will be `$(COMPRESSED_DIR)/file.txt.gz`, etc.) in the body.

Comment: @nachocab: if you have the txt.gz files already at hand you do not need a recipe within the makefile. I assumed that each .txt.gz comes from some source which will differ for each file. Therefore I created that solution.

Comment: @Etan Reisner: I've added your suggestion as alternative in my original post.

Comment: @LukasThomsen Thanks for your answer, but I have a remaining question. If I replace `final.txt: $(DEPS)` with `final.txt: $(UNCOMPRESSED_DIR)/%.txt`, I get an error:  `No rule to make target `temp_dir/%.txt', needed by `final.txt'.` Could you explain why this is wrong?

Comment: @nachocab Since `final.txt: $(UNCOMPRESSED_DIR)/%.txt` is no pattern rule (no % on the left side), make will look for a file named `"$(UNCOMPRESSED_DIR)/%.txt"`. Since it does not file such a file it looks within the makefile it there is a recipe to create it. Since the is no recipe either make terminates with an error. After a bit of research I've added another makefile to my original answer which might just be the solution you're looking for...

Comment: Thanks, but I thought that as long as there is a `%`, it is a pattern rule. That's what the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules) says. Hence my confusion. I like the `$(wildcard ...)` approach!

Answer (score 1):

You can do the gunzipping in one step:

```
my_dir:
    [ -d $@ ] || mkdir -p $@

my_dir/%.txt.gz: my_dir
    @echo "# obtaining data for $@"
    echo $* | gzip -c > $@

final.txt: my_dir/*.txt.gz
    @echo "# doing something with data for $@"
    gunzip -c $+ > $@

clean:
    rm -rf my_dir final.txt
```

The dependency `my_dir/*.txt.gz` means that `final.txt` will be made from whatever matching files happen to be present at the time (and it will fail when none are present).  To ensure the files are made when not present, you need to list them explicitly, e.g. ([if GNU Make is used](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Foreach-Function.html))

```
final.txt: $(foreach x,1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8,my_dir/$x.txt.gz)
```